# Run XSLT-script on android smartphone and/or tablet

Tags: android, xml, xslt

I have a relatively simple question:
Is there a possibility to run an xslt-script on an android device? I have an .xml file, using a .xsl script to create a new .xml file.
On windows I am using saxon, which works good, but as I don´t have always access to it I would prefer to run a script on my android phone and/or android tablet.

I did some research with google and also on this site, but i didn´t found any clear answer.

thanks in advance and greetings

Comment: Well, which version of Saxon do you use exactly, how to you use it on Windows exactly? Do you run Saxon from the command line on Windows? Or by writing .NET or Java code? I don't know how easy or supported it is to run Java command line programs like Saxon 9 or 10 or 11 on an Android device but some while ago I managed to run Saxon 9 or 10 in an Android app so the Java support on Android seems to up to run Saxon.

Comment: Some way to run XSLT 3 on Android would also be the use of my Saxon-JS 2 based XSLT 3 fiddle in the browser: https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/. You can even install it as a PWA (progressive web application) https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddlePWA/

Comment: Hello,
I am using Saxon HE 10.6 on Windows. I created a .bat file that runs the command/script.
java -jar c:\saxon\saxon-he-10.6.jar -s:input.xml -xsl:transform.xsl -o:output.xml.

So what I am searching is something similar for android. Like an android-alternative for .bat :-)  ..I tried your suggestion / your PWA, it´s working without problems, but I would prefere something comfortabler. Where I don´t have to copying the whole input.xml and the .xsl every time when I want to run the "script". 
Just like .bat for Windows.

Comment: Or eventually an app where I can run an xslt, adding the folder/source where the app can find the input.xml and the .xsl file to run the script. to get the output.xml.

Comment: Sorry for 3rd post in a row... but 
Regarding your first comment - you mean I can try to run the saxon (same version as I use on windows) on android? The only problem that would remain is how to run it with a "script".

Comment: The PWA has load and save buttons. As for running from the command line, do you use some terminal emulator on your Android devices so that you already run stuff by typing commands and running XSLT would only be an additional command? Or do you expect Saxon to provide that?

Comment: The first comment means I was able to write a prototype of an Android app that used the Saxon 10 HE library to do XQuery. So Saxon 10 as a Java library runs in an Android app, at least in the configuration I tried, only I lack the Android app development skills to build a slick GUI app for that OS.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn´t see that before. Just tested it and it works really good. So it would be a solution if I can´t find a more "functional" one. I read about the terminal emulator but I have to say that I have no idea how I can use it. No it has not to be provided by saxon.  But I need an xslt-processor to be able to transform input.xml to output.xml, or not? So as I understand all these things I need 1st an xslt-processor and 2nd a possibility to run a script which refers to the processor. (I forgot to say that I am a totally beginner)

Comment: Or is there a solution with the Android Terminal Emulator which, on my discovery tour on google and stackoverflow, I didn´t find yet?
I´m open to everything... :-)

Comment: Do you run Saxon-HE or do you happen to run EE with a license? I ask because I looked into C# development targetting various platforms including Android and it looks as if the upcoming .NET 6 MAUI (currently in preview) is a good platform for my skills to at least get an easy prototype of an app running SaxonCS to do e.g. XSLT 3 (although so far I have only loaded files from the file system for that as the existing FilePicker is mainly meant for that).

Comment: I run Saxon-HE on windows.. For my needs it's enough, so i didn't buy a license.

Comment: Understandable that HE suffices, unfortunately the new SaxonCS doesn't have a HE version. But I have run into two issues (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441092/how-to-give-path-to-download-directory-in-environment-variable-of-androidenviron, https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5386) anyway trying to get the code to run on Android that seem beyond my reach or an easy fix, so if I ever manage to get that to run on Android it will take some weeks or months.

Comment: I can wait :) no, it's not that important.. I tought that there is an easy way of running xslt with android, as like using a bat-file on windows. It would be really comfortable doing this on smartphone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a way to run both Saxon-JS 2 or rather its command line tool xslt3 as well as Saxon HE Java from a command line terminal for Android.

I installed Termux, I had to use the version from F-Droid, as the one on the Google play store seems to be no longer supported, then in the Termux terminal shell I installed node and java (try to run with e.g. ˋnodeˋ and it will tell you the ˋpkg install ...ˋ command line to install, then I did e.g. ˋnpm install -g xslt3ˋ to install Saxon-JS's command line tool and downloaded the Saxon HE 11.2 Java zip from Sourceforge with wget and unzipped it and finally I am able to run e.g. `xslt3` to run Saxon-JS or `java -jar path-to-saxon11jar` to run XSLT 3 (or in the case of Saxon Java of course XQuery too.

The interaction with the rest of the Android file system is a bit complicated to find out but the Linux Terminal shell has its own file system with a `storage` folder with sub folders like `storage/download` linked to the usual `download` folder other Android apps (e.g. your browser) use.

Here is a screenshot of Termux on my Android tablet showing the execution of Saxon HE 11 Java and Saxon-JS 2: [image].

It turns out the same procedure doesn't work quite as well on my Android phone which has Android 12 as the running Java and therefore Saxon HE 11 or any other Saxon Java HE currently does not work due to a known issue https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/7332. But Node.js and npm and therefore Saxon-JS with `xslt3` run fine on that phone.

Comment: Ok i will try that next week. First I have to understand that it all step by step :-)

Comment: It is kind of  a challenge if you are not familiar with a Linux shell, I guess, but I don't think I am able to write a better recipe for getting that up and running, you will need to see where you get and be prepared to experiment.

Comment: @AlexMutschl, did you succeed?

Comment: Hello, i had a bunch of work the last weeks and both kids were/are ill so I had not found the time yet to try. End of this week or next week I hopefully got a bit more time, then i will try it and give you some feedback.

Comment: Ok i managed to run termux, installed node and java. Downloaded and unzipped saxon to storage/emulated/0/saxon.. But I cant find out how to run now the xsl-stylesheet to transform an input.xml to output.xml. I moved the input.xml and the xsl into the /saxon folder..

Comment: Try e.g. `java -jar saxon/saxon-he-11.3.jar -s:saxon/input.xml -xsl:saxon/sheet.xsl`.

Comment: I get this message: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "java": library "libz.so.1" not found: needed by main executable -> maybe some problem with the java Install?

Comment: Does `java -version` work?

Comment: No, same error.. Tried now also on smartphone, with the same result

Comment: Which Android version is that? As I mentioned, there seems to be a problem with Android 12 and Java: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/7332

Comment: On smartphone Android 10, on Tablet Android 11 as I know (Xiaomi Pad 5)

Comment: @AlexMutschl, sorry to hear it didn't work out, perhaps you can ask Termux tagged questions on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/termux, I am afraid I don't know enough about the whole approach to tell why it did work for me but doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ok, now it works.. I had to: 'apt update && apt upgrade' before installing node and java. But now I get this message when trying to run it: Error: Unable to access jarfile saxon/saxon-he-11.3.jar

Comment: my mistake l, I had to change the directory, now it works. Thats great :)