# How to give path to Download directory in environment variable of AndroidEnvironment build file

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, maui

Using Visual Studio 2022 17.2.0 Preview 1.0 I am currently trying to create a MAUI app that already runs fine with Windows to also run under Android.

The app uses a library (SaxonCS 11) which needs to read its license file from a directory that can be given in an environment variable `SAXON_LICENSE_DIR`.

For Android, I have found I can add a `.txt` file to my project with the build action `AndroidEnvironment` to define environment variables.

However, I struggle to find the right value for the `SAXON_LICENSE_DIR` variable to point to a directory that the C# code can read.

In the Android emulator phone I put the file into the `Download` folder which the Files app shows me to be in the folder `sdk_gphone_x86_64` so I have for instance tried to set the variable to `SAXON_LICENSE_DIR=/sdk_gphone_x86_64/Download`.

When I have added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to my `AndroidManifest.xml` that directory doesn't give me an access denied directory like other attempts like `SAXON_LICENSE_DIR=/storage/emulated/0/Download` but the file is not read/found.

I guess relying on that particular emulator's directory `sdk_gphone_x86_64` is not a compatible form anyway, so my question is: how would I set an environment variable to point to the `Download` directory of the user on the Android phone so that C#/MAUI code can use that path to read out a directory in that directory?

C# code does nothing more like `static private Processor processor = new Processor();` which seems to have SaxonCS `Processor` try to look correctly for `saxon-license.lic` in the path given in `SAXON_LICENSE_DIR` but throws an exception

```
Saxon.Hej.trans.LicenseException
  message = Failed to read license file /sdk_gphone_x86_64/Download/saxon-license.lic
```

Comment: you should be able to place it in the root of your project with build action "content", and then read it using a relative path `./`

Comment: @Jason, if I understand your suggestion you want me to put the `saxon-license.lic` file into the VS project and then have it added as a "content" build action, to allow SaxonCS to read it from the application's directory, by setting e.g. `SAXON_LICENSE_DIR` to `.`? I am getting `Failed to read license file ./saxon-license.lic` in that case.

Comment: @Jason, but VS also shows a `Warning XA0101 @(Content) build action is not supported ProjectName C:\SomePath\repos\ProjectName\ProjectName\saxon-license.lic`

Comment: I haven't played much with MAUI yet, but the file needs to be in the **Android** project

Comment: @Jason, MAUI has a single project, only a `Platforms` folder with e.g. `Android`, `iOS`, `Windows`. So I am not sure exactly what you are referring to with Android **project**.

Comment: like I said, I don't know exactly how you do it in MAUI, but it needs to be done in the Android project/folder

Comment: @Jason, thanks for the suggestion, but even for the Android folder I get the warning content build action not supported and in the app the exception `Failed to read license file ./saxon-license.lic`. Let's see whether someone else has more ideas. I guess, I first have to get a better handle on file access on Android from MAUI apps, currently I am a bit lost in all the paths and special folders the various documentations for Android, Xamarin or MAUI list, kind of fail to find some easy API for MAUI that has a property or field with a DOWNLOAD folder location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70442638/how-do-i-read-a-deployed-file-in-maui-xamarin-on-android

Comment: @Jason, that asset mechanism seems nice and at works out nicely in a simple test app for Windows and Android. Now I only need to figure a way how to convince SaxonCS to use those asset streams, being XML and Java oriented it wants a Uri as a base URI for the configuration file. Still would like to know whether there is any common Android directory/folder I could in the future tell potential users of the app suggest to install their Saxon license into so that the app can find it through the SAXON_LICENSE_DIR environment variable.

Comment: I have made some progress based on the MAUI asset hint by Jason, I couldn't get SaxonCS to directly use the stream you can open with e.g. `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` but I have, I think, managed to read out the assets and copy them on the start of the app to the apps LocalApplicationData folder. I don't get any license not found that way with SaxonCS under Android but any way further seems to just crash the emulator with some fatal signal 11. No idea what that is about. Still looking for a way to set the environment variable to a known directory the user has access to and C# can read as well.